# How can find the coordinates of white circles properly with Python and image processing techniques?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I want to find the coordinates of white objects in images like below, with the help of Python and image processing:

[image] [image]

Comment: Do you want the centroids or every white pixel?

Comment: SimpleBlobDetector is a good and simple approach. other approaches would be to use or combine `cv.findContours`, `cv.moments`, `cv.connectedComponentsWithStats` https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

Comment: I want four numbers (Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax) for each white object in the image
@fmw42

Comment: Get contours and then get their bounding boxes. See cv2.findContours() and cv2.boundingRect()

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method is to use OpenCV's blob detector. See [this article](https://learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) for a tutorial. However, since this is a binary image, you could use something like the algorithm described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ckNxEwF5YU&t=3s) from the First Principles of Computer Vision lecture leries. If you're interested in Computer Vision, I would recommend watching that whole series. It's fantastic.

If you use blob detection, you must set the blob colour like this:

```py
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

params.filterByColor = True
params.blobColor = 255

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
```

This will detect white dots on a black background. Set blobColor to 0 for black dots on a white background.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case, blob detector in OpenCV couldn't find the position of objects properly (due to the structure of some objects  that aren't kind of circle), I finally solved the problem with the help of `cv.connectedComponentsWithStats`